# In sorted table, how many records in end of result are equals to the last item

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a Table with `Sort` and `Status` fields.
I need to create a Query with 2 fields: `LastStatus` and `Times`.
First field shows (sorting per Sort) the status of last record. The second shows how many records, in end of table, has the same value.

### Example

When the query result is this:

| Sort | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | alpha |
| 2 | bravo |
| 3 | charlie |
| 4 | alpha |
| 5 | alpha |
| 6 | charlie |
| 7 | alpha |
| 8 | alpha |
| 9 | alpha |

Expected result:

| LastStatus | Times |
| --- | --- |
| alpha | 3 |

Thanks!

Comment: How to recognize the end of the table?

Answer (score 4):

On second read, it is more of a Gaps-and-Islands problem

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zo8L7rnx)**

```
with cte as (
Select [Sort]
      ,[Status]
      ,Grp = row_number() over (order by Sort)
            -row_number() over (partition by [Status] order by Sort)
 From YourTable
 )
 Select top 1 
        [Status]
       ,Times = sum(1)
  From  cte
  Group By Grp,[Status]
  Order by max([Sort]) desc
```

**Results**

```
Status  Times
alpha   3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use window function(lead and First_value for find  Times

```
select Status LastStatus,times
from (
        select 
              Status
            ,lastvalue- First_value(sort) over(order by  lg desc   ) +1  
            as times
            ,sort
             ,row_number() over (order by Sort desc) as rw
        from (
                select *,

                    max(Sort) over (order by Sort desc) as lastvalue,
                    Last_value(Status) over (order by Sort desc) as lastStatus,

                     case when 
                     lead(Status) over(order by sort desc)!=Status then 1 else 0 end as lg
                 from L
        )a
        where lg=1
    
)a
where rw=1
```